# How to get a user and attach it to a review, then send the result to view using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, view

```
$http.get("api/location/getReviews/" + $routeParams.id) 
.success(function (data) { 
  $scope.reviews = {}; 
  $scope.reviews = data; 
  angular.forEach($scope.reviews, 
    function (value, index) { 
      $http.get("api/user/" + value.UserId) 
      .success(function (user) { 
        $scope.value.User = user; 
      }); 
    }); 
  });
```

I have the following code and what I am trying to do is to get the user 
from `userId`, attach it to a review, and send it into view because my review has a `userId` and I need the user's email. When I list the reviews, I want to show the email and not the id, but I don't know how to do this. It gives me cannot read property or undefined User.

Anyone can explain what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the user object returned from the API call in the loop into the indexed review object in the reviews Array this way :

```
    angular.forEach($scope.reviews, function (value, index) {

            $http.get("api/user/" + value.UserId)
            .success(function (user) {

                  $scope.reviews[index].User = user;

            });

   });
```